# Server negotiated HTTP/2 with blacklisted suite

Tags: http, cipher-selection

I understand there are quite a few posts regarding my error message, and I have looked at them with no luck to resolving my own issue.

Essentially, certain web browsers are unable to load my site because of the following blacklisted suites

> Server negotiated HTTP/2 with blacklisted suite
>
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

My Nginx configurations contain the following

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers HIGH:!DH:!ECDH:!CAMELLIA:!SRP:!PSK:!MD5:!KRB5;
```

What needs to be changed in my ssl_ciphers? Or, what resources can I look into that will give me a direction?

Comment: You should allow ECDHE suites.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Would you be able to explain to me how you came to that conclusion?

Comment: List of disallowed cipher suites in HTTP/2: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540#appendix-A

Answer (score 3):

These suits included in the list of ciphersuites prohibited by HTTP/2 defined in [RFC 7540](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#appendix-A).

Since AES-GCM and RSA still enjoy a good reputation, the remaining weakness of the second suite is that it doesn't offer forward-secrecy.

The specification confirms this:

> This list includes those cipher suites **that do not offer an ephemeral key exchange** *[this rules out both of your suites]* and those that are based on the TLS null, stream, or block cipher type *[this rules out TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]*

In your config string I see `!DH` and more importantly `!ECDH` which disables all kinds of Diffie-Hellman suites, including ephemeral Diffie-Hellman, which are the way SSL achieves forward secrecy.

> [**ECDH**](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Ciphers(1))
>
> cipher suites using ECDH key exchange, including anonymous, ephemeral and fixed ECDH.

Thus the fix is to allow ephemeral elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman (ECDHE)

Comment: Also, ECDH suites are generally considered state of the art and the best to enable, so it doesn't make sense from an HTTP 1.1 + TLS perspective to disable them, either.